# Change the organization of a Twitter Fabric App

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

So I'm using Twitter Fabric for analytics and beta testing on an iOS app, and so far I've had it in my default "Root" organization that Fabric automatically creates. Now I have a collaborator and want him to be able to work on the app as well.

The documentation makes it pretty clear how to do this - create a new organization and add your team member to the organization. What it does not make clear is **how to change the organization of an app**.

Currently my app is in my Root organization, I want to move it into the new organization I've just created, but there is no way I can see to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to do this.

Given this: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html#add-organizations

> We currently don’t allow apps to be transferred between organizations. If you’d like to move an app to a new organization (for example, if you are turning app development over to a new team or a different company), you will need to remove the app from your current organization and onboard it into the new organization.

Is stated within the given link.

Comment: okay, and what should I do to switch between my organisations in IDE plugin?

Comment: Jake Alsemgeest is absolutely right, I also faced this trouble and that is the solution..

Comment: How do you remove the app from its current org and onboard it to a new org?